# Use Bootstrap only for its Form styling

Tags: css, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap, django-crispy-forms

I have a Django website already complete with its CSS. One of its templates has a form. As anyone familiar with Django forms, the most common way to style it nicely is by using crispy form or Bootstrap. However, with my CSS already in place whenever I use either of the above solution, the website appearance gets messed up.

**Things I have already done and attempted:**

- placed the Bootstrap stylesheet before my own stylesheet
- override Bootstrap but realised it was so tedious when I only want to style a single form

***Is there a way to use only the Form styling of Bootstrap so it doesn't mess up the rest of my stylesheet?***

Comment: Use the **[customiser tool](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/)**, that lets you just take the CSS for specific elements.

Comment: Tried that as well but I still have to override multiple features that are not related to form. Is it the only choice left for me?

Answer (score 0):

django widget tweaks seems to be the solution for my problem. It saves me a lot of time and it allows me to edit forms on template level (instead of editing at forms.py).